# x**-0.5: what is the - before ** performing?

Tags: python, square-root

while finding a square-root, we perform number**0.5, but what is the meaning of - sign before 0.5.

I was looking at a code (I was specificially looking at [ViT Code](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-image-models/blob/main/timm/models/vision_transformer.py), and here for scaling, they have added:

```
self.scale = self.head_dim ** -0.5
```

Please help me understanding it meaning. I did few experiments on my terminal but did not understand what's happening:

```
>>> a = 4
>>> a**0.5
2.0
>>>
>>> a**-0.5
0.5
```

Comment: It's just a negative sign. `a ** ( - 0.5)`

Comment: Look for "Negative exponents" here: [Exponentiation - Wikipdeia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation).

Comment: @mousetail Yeah, sorry I missed the fact that negative sign is just reciprocal (I knew it just could not recollect). Thanks for the answers. I will accept it once the timer is off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reciprocal. `x**-n == 1/(x**n)`.......